# how to create pull request between non master branches

Tags: git, github

suppose I have 3 branches: master, A, B. now I want to pull request from A to B, how can I do that? I know how to pull request from A, B to master but not from A to B

Comment: You should able to figure this out yourself, and if not, there'll be a blog post somewhere explaining it. However, I'll tell you@ change the base branch to branch B. It defaults to master but it is changeable.

Comment: Where are you stuck? How do you create the PR to master?

Comment: sorry, i did that, Legorooj helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the pull request, select `B` instead of `master` in the "base" (= target branch) dropdown